# Where should warden callbacks be placed in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I'm relatively new to rails. I have Devise set up, and want to run some callback code after users sign in.

Looking at the [Warden wiki page](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks), I can use the "after_set_user" callback to perform this logic, for example:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|
  unless user.active?
    auth.logout
    throw(:warden, :message => "User not active")
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure where I should be storing this stuff. My first thought is that I could put it in config/initializers/devise.rb. Is that correct? It doesn't feel right putting what is essentially controller code in the config directory.

Comment: Looks like a filter, "after_set_user" that is, my guess is a controller.

Comment: Actually I found a section in initializers/devise.rb named "Warden configuration", so I guess that _is_ the correct place to put it.

Comment: Did you find where to put this code? Or did you adapt it to the Devise initializer's code style somehow?

Comment: I put it at the bottom of config/initializers/devise.rb. I don't think there is a way to do it using native Devise code. In this case I needed to do some OAuth profile merge stuff so called a method in my user model from there.

Comment: Just FYI, I learnt somewhere else the code should go on the User model. It's working for me now.

Comment: @dgilperez how could you put in User model?

Comment: @Bero just as it is on the answer, inside the model code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Warden hooks need to be required when your application is booting, so inside Devise's initializer at ***config/initializers/devise.rb*** is a good candidate.

However, the behavior you want to achieve will be better accomplished by using this Devise feature:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in