# Ruby On Rails authentication with Devise and (warden) callbacks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin, warden

I have a rails app that is using Devise, with a User model, no scope. 
I've also added activeadmin gem in to the app, Active Admin is a gem used for adding an admin dashboard in your application. It uses Devise for logging in users and creates a separate admin_user model for the admins.

I am allowing anonymous, non-logged in users to create shopping carts, creating a `session[:cart_id]`. If a user logs in I want associate the user with the cart, something like

```
Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).user = current_user
```

I was planning to use Wardens callbacks [wardens callbacks](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks) to impliment this, something like so :

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user :scope => :user do |user, auth, opts|

    Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).user = user 

end
```

However I get an error if I do that:

`<% unless user_signed_in? %>` throws an error `:admin_user user is not logged in`

Anyone got any ideas what is going on?

I've looked at related questions, but no help:

[How to access session from Warden/Devise after_authentication callback in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679864/how-to-access-session-from-warden-devise-after-authentication-callback-in-rails)

[Where should warden callbacks be placed in a rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375853/where-should-warden-callbacks-be-placed-in-a-rails-app)

Comment: What does Active Admin have to do with your example?  I am guess that is the problem, you don't know why admin_user is showing up?

Comment: I implemented ActiveAdmin with a single user, I didn't want to user a separate admin_user.  With that your authentication is integrated, a single devise class.  Then there are roles per user.  If you are interested in that solution, I can explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turned out the issue was solved by setting the default scope in warden,in the devise initializer file.

```
  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user
```

Since the active admin routes were added above the devise routes for my user, the adminuser became the default user.

Answer (score 2):

The `AdminUser` model that Active Admin uses also executes this callback. So, maybe, an if can solve your problem:

```
 Warden::Manager.after_set_user :scope => :user do |user, auth, opts|
   Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).user = user if user.class == User
 end
```

Comment: That still was throwing the error referred to in the question.